# Converting loadrunner script to Neoload (using Fiddler maybe?)

Tags: scripting, fiddler, loadrunner, neoload

Pretty much exactly what it says on the tin: I have a Loadrunner script and I would like to convert it to a Neoload one. There's no way to do this automatically, obviously, but my idea was to capture traffic created by a loadrunner playthrough and then somehow reroute it (or export it?) to Neoload, and then do the manual extraction/whatever later.

The answer given [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70847bc1-0418-4a2c-afc9-f76821e8f6cc/script-and-project-conversion-from-neoload-and-loadrunner) gives some tantalizing hints on how to do it, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to get Neoload to accept anything other than manual recording (the answer is given for Webtest because Fiddler can export a Webtest file, but there's no such option for Neoload). Is there a viable way to make this approach work, or is there a different option I could explore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NeoLoad records the HTTP traffic through a Proxy (default recording method). All you need to do is:

1. Tell LoadRunner to play the script through a Proxy: NeoLoad machine, port 8090 (default NeoLoad recording port)
2. Launch a NeoLoad recording (you can uncheck "Launch Browser")
3. Launch the LoadRunner playback of 1 VU
4. Stop NeoLoad recording

I hope this helps,

Christophe
Neotys

Comment: Ah, really, that simple? That sounds great, thank you! After testing it, though, it seems like I don't have admin privileges on my machine to change Loadrunner settings; I can only change Neoload. Is there an alternative method of working around this restriction? I'll try to get admin privileges, but I might have to find another route. Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: Okay, I managed to test around with it on a colleague's computer (for some reason, his machine can change the settings). Apologies if this is a stupid question, but what do you mean by Neoload machine in step one? Do you mean IP address, machine address, or some other number? I tried both and neither worked.

Comment: Solution for posterity! 1. Change your VUgen settings to localhost / 8090. 2. Change your IE settings to the same. 3. If your machine is anything like mine, click on "exceptions" for VUGen proxy and get rid of anything there. 4. Play and record! Although sometimes this sputzes out without warning, I'm not sure how to fix it. (Yet.)

Answer (score 0):

There no good conversion between the scripts.
Creating a script in that way would generate only the HTTP requests.
It would NOT generate:
1. Script changes (conditions, loops, etc)
2. Library attachments
3. Parameterizations 
4. Validations
and extra stuff

Answer (score 0):

Since Neoload 6.5.0 there is a new tool called 
LoadRunner Converter.
The LoadRunner converter provides the capability to convert LoadRunner HTTP scripts to their NeoLoad equivalent for those organizations that currently use LoadRunner and want to move on to NeoLoad.

See:

- https://www.neotys.com/neoload/whats-new